# Do people in Colorado typically say "attorney" or "lawyer?"

Tags: expressions, synonyms, phrase-usage, common-word

I'm interested to know if people in the Colorado area say attorney or lawyer more frequently.

Comment: Kim - why Colorado?

Comment: All over the USA, _attorney_ is what lawyers call themselves, and prefer to be called and referred to. But unless they're trying to impress a lawyer, most Americans say _lawyer_.

Comment: So far as I can tell, Colorado isn't known for having markedly different speech patterns from the rest of the West. Moreover, the population is heavily concentrated along the Fort Collins-Denver-Colorado Springs corridor, which is full of carpetbaggers.

Comment: @choster What branch of the law do they practise?

Comment: @JohnLawler My experience is that *attorney* is used in more formal speech and *lawyer* more conversationally, even among esquires.

Comment: @WS2 Not criminal defense for marijuana offenses, that's for certain.

Comment: I was elected Sheriff at a chuckwagon extravaganza in the Southwest. Are pink Stetsons the usual headgear?

Comment: No, @EdwinAshworth, they're pretty selective about the hats. ;-)

Comment: I think in Colorado they say "shyster".

Comment: @andi - I'd have stopped at "why?"

Comment: [Books seem to prefer Coloradan lawyers](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=colorado+lawyer%2Ccolorado+attorney&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Ccolorado%20lawyer%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BColorado%20Lawyer%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BColorado%20lawyer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ccolorado%20attorney%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BColorado%20attorney%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BColorado%20Attorney%3B%2Cc0), but that only examines when the word is immediately preceded by the word Colorado.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any reason to suppose that *lawyer* and *attorney* are used any differently in Colorado than in the rest of the United States. I have lived for multiple years (at various times) in Texas, Maryland, Washington, D.C., New York, and California, and it seems to me that in spoken English in all of those places *lawyer* was a more common word than *attorney*. But as bib suggests in a comment above, *attorney* may be used in more-formal contexts and *lawyer* in more-informal ones by the same speaker.

In written English, American English shows a steady preference for *lawyer* over *attorney* in the most generic usage situation. Here is an Ngram chart of two generic phrases ("an attorney" [green line] and "a lawyer" [yellow line]) and two specific and somewhat more formal phrases ("practicing attorney" [blue line] and "practicing lawyer" [red line]) from 1900 through 2005:

[image]

The most striking thing about this chart (aside from the predictable advantage in popularity of the generic forms  over the specific forms) is the remarkable overall consistency of the gap between "a lawyer" and "an attorney" across this 106-year period.

If we remove the two generic forms from the chart, however, and thereby change the scale of the resulting line graph, we get this chart for "practicing attorney" (blue line) versus "practicing lawyer" (red line):

> [image]

In this setting *lawyer* loses much (perhaps all) of its advantage over *attorney* in U.S.-published English. In my view, this strongly supports bib's comment, "My experience is that *attorney* is used in more formal speech and *lawyer* more conversationally, even among esquires."